# Where to place factory method?

Tags: c#, factory

I'm implementing factory pattern to support report generation using 2 different reporting libraries (Crystal Reports and DevExpress).

So I created a `Default` class library project and added an `IReport` interface to it. I then created 2 further class library projects, each having a class that implements `IReport.`

Additionally, in my `Default` project I also added a "Factory" class:

```
public sealed class ReportFactory : IReportFactory
{
    public IReport Get(string extension)
    {
        switch (extension.ToLower())
        {
            case "rpt":
                //TODO create crystal report instance
                break;

            case "rpx":
                //TODO create devexpress report instance
                break;

            default:
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(extension));
        }
    }
}
```

My main app has a reference just to the `Default` project. My problem is:

Where do I need to have the factory class so that I can create the concrete classes without adding unnecessary references to my main project?

Comment: You obviously cannot do that in the Default project as that would cause a circular dependency. Normally you'd have another project that references all 3 projects you have there and is referenced by your application project, but do notice that the main project will still have transitive dependencies to all 3 projects as that's how .NET works

Comment: In your main project, all you need is: `IReport`. So you just need to reference `Default`. Sure you will need the others assemblies but you don't need a reference to them. Let me know if this doesn't work for some reason.